# Jinja check every loop index value

Tags: python-3.x, jinja2

how can i do this in jinja condition

My goal is to check the value of value_index every index of the loop if the next index value is same then it will not print . until the next value is not equal to value_index it will print it.

sample data:

```
users = [ ('username1','password1'),('username2','password1') ]
contacts  = [('0909','0909','0011','0011','0011','0908')]
```

so far i have this code but its not working as i expected

```
{% for items in users %}
  {% set i = loop %}
  {% set value_index = '' %}
  {% print(items[0]) %}

  {% for item in contacts %} 
     {% if value_index  != item  %}
        {% print(item) %}  
    {% endif %} 
    {% set value_index = item %}

  {% endfor %} 
{% endfor %}
```

My expected output is

```
username1
0909
0011
0908
username2
0909
0011
0908
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you're looking for `loop.changed(*val)` method: https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/#for (see table). So, you just need to call the method in your `if` tag like this:

```
{% for items in users %}
  {% print(items[0]) %}

  {% for item in contacts %}
     {% if loop.changed(item)  %}
        {{ item }}
     {% endif %} 
  {% endfor %} 
{% endfor %}
```

If the value of `item` actually changed from the previous call of `loop.changed` the result of the call is `true`. `false` otherwise.

Comment: Works like a charm! @sergei sadovnikov THANK YOU! :) :D